# learning hyper parameters: are we allowed to touch the prior parameters after observing the data?

Tags: bayesian, prior, philosophical, hyperparameter

There are many algorithms/applications that aim to learn the hyper parameters i.e. the parameters of a prior distribution from the observed data. A typical algorithm works in an iterative function where we optimise some cost function for a given set of hyper parameter values and then the next step is to update the hyper parameters using the current estimates of the other model parameters. Perhaps the EM algorithm works this way?

My question is more philosophical. I thought that the priors should be fixed and should not depend on the data at all as they reflect our belief before we observe any data. So is tuning the hyper parameters not slightly unprincipled?

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to something else? In most cases we fix the prior and then learn the parameter of the posterior. The parameter of the posterior is not the prior. The EM algorithm is updating $\theta$ each time, but this $\theta$ is the parameter for the posterior not the prior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! May I clarify, so take an example, we have some subset of the model parameters $x$ and some observed data $y$ and we have a prior on $x$, with a hyper parameter $\mu$. So, I set the value of $\mu$ to say $\mu_0$. Now, I do some optimisation and can $P(x|y)$ and using my current estimate of $x$, I can somehow get an update for $\mu$, call it $\mu_n$. Then I am allowed to use this newly estimated hyper parameter to do the bayesian update again for $P(x|y)$?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes this kind of approach is common in a lot of algorithms. The very popular MCMC method in general relies on this kind of updating. Think of it as your algorithm finding/searching areas in the high dimensional parameter space where there is a lot of likelihood/probability.

Comment: Even further, Bayesian hierarchical models rely on this kind of information sharing through the parameters of priors as a way to reduce variance in parameters where there is not a lot of data being used.

Comment: With that said, I don't have any mathematical justification or citations, so I won't submit an answer.

Comment: Thank you! I, somehow, at the moment fail to understand why this "probably converges" to a good solution. The way I sort of see it, is that ok given some fixed values we explore the space and evaluate the likelihoods and then when we reach a stationary point, we use it to update these other hyper parameters. Now, this hopefully takes us to a new location in the search space and we explore that and so on until we reach some sort of a stationary point wrt to all these parameters. I am not sure if this is the right way to think about this though or if it even makes sense.

Comment: It will vary depending on the algorithm. Some algorithms will just get stuck in a local (but potentially global) optimum because the updates are deterministic (EM). Some algorithms have stochastic updates (MCMC) so they are more likely to move around the whole parameter space instead of get isolated to one stationary point.